# ADGV C# DataGridView - update query bug?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, sql-update

I'm trying to use auto-generated advancedDataGrid - ADGV ([adgv.codeplex.com](https://adgv.codeplex.com)).

Problem is that the below shown procedure does not succeed  with updating the SQL table every time... It is exactly **every second Event** raised...

```
private void advancedDataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIdx = advancedDataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)advancedDataGridView1.Rows[rowIdx].DataBoundItem;
        DataRow dr = drv.Row;
        this.levTableAdapter.Update(dr); //strange, but Update is done every second time....
    }
```

How to debug it?, if I add another line of this.levTableAdapter.Update(dr) - it will not help either...

EDIT:
Looked into behaviour again and I have to update:

```
1st enter "A" - noChangeSQL, Event picks "A", "A" in the datagrid cell.
2nd enter "B" -  "A" in SQL, Event picks "A", "A" in cell.
3rd enter "C" -  "A" in SQL, Event picks "C", "C" in cell.
4rd enter "D" -  "C" in SQL, Event picks "C", "C" in cell.
5th enter "E" -  "C" in SQL, Event picks "E", "E" in cell.
```

Comment: what do you mean every second time?

Comment: if I edit cell for the first (3rd, 5th, etc.) time (CellEndEdit event raised) - SQL Table cell is not updated. It updates when I edit the DataGrid cell for the second (4th, 6th, etc.) time.

Comment: Is the event raised each time? And when the table is updated, is it picking the value from the previous edit or the current one?

Comment: event is raised every time, it is picking the current value...

Comment: Had to edit the "results" in the first post... something wrong with Events....

Comment: Well, when you are in the event, what is the RowState of that dr? It's "Unchanged" right? And yet, you just changed that row. Whatever upddates that RowState property, is sometime *later* in the sequence of actions. The grid's CellEndEdit is executed before, and then some time after that, the DataRow's RowState will get set to Modified. And that's the thing your adapter is looking at, when it's executing that Update. this is excactly what using the BeginInvoke to run the adapter.Update will cure. It defers the execution of Update to the next time UI thread event loop gets around to it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Now I understand the reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure, it's every second event? Could it be it doesn't save just the last row you changed? If it is a timing issue or excecution order problem (like row state update happening after EndEdit event gets handled), you can defer it a bit, with Form's BeginInvoke, like this:

```
private void advancedDataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIdx = advancedDataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)advancedDataGridView1.Rows[rowIdx].DataBoundItem;
    DataRow dr = drv.Row;
    BeginInvoke((Action)(() => SaveRowChanges(dr)));
}

private void SaveRowChanges(DataRow dr)
{
    DataRow[] rows = { dr };
    adapter.Update(rows);
}
```