# ADGV C# DataGridView - programatically call CellLeave Event

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datepicker, event-handling

I'm trying to use auto-generated advancedDataGrid - ADGV ([adgv.codeplex.com](https://adgv.codeplex.com)).
Current question is similar to the solved question before: [my previous stackoverflow.com question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513792/adgv-c-sharp-datagridview-update-query-bug/46514435#46514435)

I have a Form (frmLev) with advancedDataGrid filled with data from SQL. One column of DataGridView is a date field (DD.MM.YYYY) with DateTimePicker placed there.

If I get it right...The problem is in that the full row will be saved to SQL only when cell edit is finished manually *after* user picks the date in DatePicker. The cell looks like the edit is finished, but it has to be confirmed again by clicking, pressing enter or tab. Other text cells are with text selected or blinking cursor.

I want to save the row to SQL at the end of delDatePick_textChange(), but calling currentRowSave() will not work at this moment. User has to perform a click first. Data will be saved only when levDGV_CellLeave() get the event.

**QUESTION IS: How to programatically fire CellLeave Event?**

```
MetroFramework.Controls.MetroDateTime delDatePick = new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroDateTime();
Rectangle _Rectangle; 


    private void frmLev_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add DateTimePicker to Date
            levDGV.Controls.Add(delDatePick);
            delDatePick.Visible = false;
            delDatePick.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
            delDatePick.TextChanged += new EventHandler(delDatePick_textChange);
            delDatePickValueAutomatic = false;
    }

private void levDGV_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (levDGV.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText)
        {
            case "Datum":
            _Rectangle = levDGV.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
            delDatePick.Size = new Size(_Rectangle.Width, _Rectangle.Height);
            delDatePick.Location = new Point(_Rectangle.X, _Rectangle.Y);
            delDatePick.Visible = true;
                if (levDGV.CurrentCell.Value != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    delDatePick.Value = (DateTime)levDGV.CurrentCell.Value;
                    delDatePickValueAutomatic = true;
                }
            break;
        }
    }

private void delDatePick_textChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (delDatePickValueAutomatic != false) // event fired when cell gets focused, so skipping
        {
            String pickedDate = delDatePick.Text.ToString();
            delDatePick.Visible = false;

            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {levDGV.CurrentCell.Value = pickedDate;});
            levDGV.Refresh();
            delDatePick.Visible = false;
            //I want to update SQL row here, but calling currentRowSave() will not work at this moment because row is in edit mode...
        }
    }

private void levDGV_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //skipping first entrance;
        if (e.ColumnIndex != 0 && e.RowIndex != 0)
        {
            delDatePick.Visible = false;
            currentRowSave();
        }
    }

private void currentRowSave()
    {
        int rowIdx = levDGV.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)levDGV.Rows[rowIdx].DataBoundItem;
        DataRow dr = drv.Row;
        BeginInvoke((Action)(() => SaveRowChanges(dr)));
    }
```

Comment: You can call the method normally, all you have to do is create a `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` and populate it.

Comment: added levDGV_CellLeave(levDGV, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(1, levDGV.CurrentCell.RowIndex)); - Method is firing, but cell is still in edit mode...

Answer (score 1):

You can also call cell's EndEdit() method. Something like this:

```
this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => levDGV.CurrentCell.EndEdit()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround... It does not answer my question, but works for me.

```
this.BindingContext[levDGV.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit(); //does not call CellLeave
currentRowSave();
```

Comment: Unhiding a calendar control on grid's CellClick has the disadvantage that it only responds to mouse clicks. There are other ways to start cell edit, F2 for example. It is generally better idea to make your own custom DataGridViewColumn derivate. Basically, what you want is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells

And then, you can do your DB update in grid's CellEndEdit handler.